# Swift 3 conversion : value of type 'characterset' has no member 'characterIsMember'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am currently converting my codes to swift 3 and i encounter the above mentioned error with the following codes.

```
 func containsAlphabets() -> Bool {
    //Checks if all the characters inside the string are alphabets
    let set = NSCharacterSet.letters
    return self.utf16.contains( { return set.characterIsMember($0)  } )
}
```

Any kind souls can assist on this?

Comment: Hey it worked! @LeoDabus THANK YOU!

Comment: Oh I am new to SO and thank you for highlighting! Will heed your advice and sure you can post it as the answer :) @LeoDabus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit/update: **Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var containsLetters: Bool { contains { $0.isLetter } }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3, `CharacterSet` is re-designed to work well with `UnicodeScalar` rather than UTF-8 code point.

In this case, you can write something like this:

```
var containsAlphabets: Bool {
    //Checks if any of the characters inside the string are alphabets
    return self.unicodeScalars.contains {CharacterSet.letters.contains($0)}
}
```

Please try.